# 1.When converting tensorflow model to tflite model, is there any way to fix the output order during inference using tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow

When converting tensorflow model to tflite model, is there any way to fix the output order during inference using tflite

Facing an issue of output order of tflite inference on meraki custom cv

When converting tensorflow model to tflite model, is there any way to fix the output order during inference using tflite

Facing an issue of outpt order of tflite inference on meraki custom cv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.